# Issue with css url request

Tags: php, html, css

I'll try to explain the issue the best I can: I have two css uploads methods. The first one is with `link rel` and is working fine. 
The second one (for performance issues), goes inside the css file and print directly the css into the page.

```
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL_SITE; ?>style/index.css" /> -->
<style>
    <?php
        $urlstyle = URL_SITE.'style/index.css?m='.(int) IS_ON_MOBILE;
        $style = file_get_contents($urlstyle);
        echo $style;
    ?>
</style>
```

There is absolutely no doubt about what is loaded. Those two methods returns the same css.
As an example we can use this part of the css

```
.wrapper-accueil .scroll:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url("../assets/img/picto/arrow-down.svg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

As you can see, there is an url inside.
When trying to load the css with the first method, the path is fine. Everything works fine.

But here comes the issues, when I try my second method writting this css inside the file where it's called. The url path of the css is wrong. (I shouldn't have the first `../` to make it works.

But here is the thing. Even if this code shouldn't be working with the second method. The file is loaded properly with no problem. And I can't understand why it's working. (And the cache is cleared ne doubt about that neither). 
More stranger things, when I upload the website on server and i'm no longer in localhost, then there is indeed an issue and the file isn't found as it should be.

So working in localhost while it shouldn't. Not working in server while it should indeed not be working.

But I have something more stranger again, I got an other website. Same framework (that means same folder/file structure), same css file, same way of including the file. And with this one using the second method, the file is found in localhost and in server too...while it shouldn't be working with none of them.

I hope you have any idea cause I'm lost at this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper-accueil .scroll:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url("../../assets/img/picto/arrow-down.svg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
}

May be you have a folder containing picto has on another folder
```

Comment: As I said all the files and folder are identical inside the framework. So nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get 100% what your problem is, but it seems that you load your css with relative paths from two different starting points:

1. Loaded with link:

   ```
   www.example.com/path/to/your/application/style/index.css
   => this loads the asset from:
   www.example.com/path/to/your/application/assets/img/picto/arrow-down.svg
   ```
2. Included in site:

   ```
   www.example.com/path/to/your/application/site.php
   => this loads the asset from:
   www.example.com/path/to/your/assets/img/picto/arrow-down.svg
                              ^^^
               note the missing path due to "../" in your svg path
   ```

Maybe this is the answer to your problem, feel free to clarify if I didn't get you correctly! Please also check the developer console, especially the "Network" tab in Chrome and see what exactly is requested and double check the paths there.

Comment: It's not really the answer it's more the problem himself.The issue is: with both of your version (1 and 2) the file is still loaded. But how can he be loaded if the path is wrong ? That's what I'm trying to understand.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay then the best chance would be to check the network tab in chromes developer tools. There you can see exactly what is loaded and why (i.e. where the call is coming from). And in the console you should get at least an error when there is a wrong path requested.

Comment: If this doesn't help the next step would be to remove all unnecessary code until it works/breaks. Maybe you have the css somewhere else and that's why it always works? ...coding is 50% fun and 50% searching for issues like this one ;)

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to do since this morning...I will come back around here if I have some intell.

Comment: I guess I found something with a tricky htaccess, it might come from there. If you can have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51722165/htaccess-syntax-rewriterule/51722413#51722413