# Htaccess syntax RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to try to understand some of my htaccess rules but I can't succeed to find the proper documentation.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{1,2})?\/?style\/(.*).css$ site/scripts/concat-files.php?type=css&page=$2&lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Question 1:
I guess this rule is triggered by something like this. `<link rel="stylesheet" src =<?php echo URL ?>"/en/style/accueil.css">`
Am I right ?

Question 2: I know QSA allow to keep the request parameter from the first url to the rewrite URL. But what L is doing ?

Question 3 : Is the rule triggered by this kind of things ?

```
$urlstyle = URL."en/style/accueil.css";
$style = file_get_contents($urlstyle);
```

Thanks.

EDIT: Then considering this

```
$urlstyle = URL_SITE.'en/style/accueil.css';
$style = file_get_contents($urlstyle);
echo $style;
```

The style is written.

But in my concat-files.php

I have this

```
$pathfile= PATH . $file;
$sContenu = @file_get_contents( $pathfile);
if( $sContenu !== false) {
    echo $sContenu;
}
```

It means that accueil css will be written 2 times no ?

But in my code I have it only once.

Comment: Question 2: [RewriteRule flags documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html). Questions 1 & 3: yes.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
As @nick said in the comments
1 - The rule is triggered by any http request that satisfy the rule itself. or rather :

```
`1 or 2 alphabetic characters` / style / `any string`.css
```

2 - `[L]` means thats only first rule will apply, other rules match will be ignored.

3 - Yes, as i said The rule is triggered by any http request that satisfy the rule itself

**Edit2**

No, it seems that you are not outputting same content two times.

```
$style = file_get_contents($urlstyle);
```

You are assigning to `$style` the content of an url (generated by some php code).
Is a different behaviour from, for example, `include` function, in that case both pieces of code would  be  executed and written two times.
So its ok that you have it only once.

Comment: Actually 'any string with chars or numbers' can only be 1 or 2 alphabetic characters ([a-z]{1,2}) and it is optional, as is the first `/`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/issdu9/3 for examples for 1. that work and won't work.

Comment: @JohannesStadler see nick comment, your 2 last examples are wrong.

Comment: @NicolòCozzani sorry I didn't clarify that more precisely: Only the first two examples match the regex that's why they are highlighted. The other two examples don't match as you correctly said, but I added them to show that the Question 1 is incorrectly answered in the questions comment.